# Relative layout issue with IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Have a problem with relative positioned span and img not being correctly positioned in IE7.
You can see the problem at:

http://bookgroupaustralia.obiweb.com.au/

The 'NEW' and 'SALE' spans should be top right of the title, and the cart image in the bottom right. They are correctly positioned in IE8,FF,Safari,Chrome. In IE7 they are appearing lowers than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 doesn't appear to be picking up the margin correctly.

Try setting a `position: relative;` declaration on your `productItem` class.  Then instead of setting margin values for your `.listing span.badge` classes, try setting the following values:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

You'll also need to do the shopping cart icon (your `img.cart` class).  Again, you want this image to be absolutely positioned at the bottom right corner of each list item:

```
.listing ul li.productItem img.cart, .listing ul li.productItemLast img.cart {
    bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
```

You may want to adjust the bottom and right positions a bit.
That should take care of it.

Comment: setting position relative on productItem class results in all the cart images appearing at the bottom of the page at the same y position.

Comment: Good point; overlooked that one.  Updated answer accordingly.